# What is correct/clean Switch (or functions in general) control flow?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I stumbled upon a bug with my switch statement (two cases) wherein both cases ran because the former made the latter true. I found two solutions, but I don't know which one I should use or if I should combine both.

My initial thought was simply to add breaks at the end of each case. But my coworker suggested I swap the order as the latter can't interfere with the former that way. Maybe I should do both? I think breaks are clearer at a glance, but swapping them is elegant. **What would you prefer to see from your coworker?**

```
**---OPTION 1---**
var created = false;
function clicker(){
    switch(created){
        case false:
            **some code**
            created = true;
            break;
        case true:
            **some code**
            break;
    }
}

**---OPTION 2---**
var created = false;
function clicker(){
    switch(created){
        case true:
            **some code**
        case false:
            **some code**
            created = true;
    }
}
```

Initially, I ran option 1 but without the breaks. Case "false" would run, make case "true" = true, then case "true" would run.

**Both of these options fix it. Which is better? Do you have an even better solution?**

Comment: I would prefer neither, `switch` is ugly, verbose, and error-prone IMO. Use `if` / `else` statements instead, or possibly an object. `if (created) { handleCreated(); } else { handleNotCreated(); }`

Comment: You could `return;` in a switch within a function, instead of `break;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an `if` statement:

```
function clicker() {
    if (created) {
        //Some code
    } else {
        //Some code
        created = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems the other comments agree. Thanks for the help :)